# how to write a ,csv file in plsql which when opened in ms excel gives me a new sheet?

Tags: csv, plsql, export-to-csv, plsqldeveloper

Currently I have a table table_1 from which I write a file file_1.csv This can be opened in excel.
I need to write contexts of table_2 to the same csv in a different worksheet.

Therefore file_1 needs to have 2 sheets. One for table_1 and the other for table_2.

Answer (score 1):

CSV per definition is only one worksheet. So this cannot be done.